# Pass data from Shopify URL to saved order

Tags: shopify

What is a method of passing custom data through a Shopify URL and having that data stored with the order (for later extraction through reports, admin access, API pull, etc.)?

For example, I would like to produce URLs like

> examplestore.com/products/soccerball?aff=123456

(for an external affiliate tracking system), and have that **123456** be saved with the order.  Then I could pull the orders from Shopify and know which orders were associated with which affiliates.

I realize there are affiliate apps for use within Shopify, but they seem to want to own the affiliate definition and data.  This isn't what I need, as the IDs I pass in are entirely owned and managed by an external system.

Comment: I'm a bit bewildered at how this question could be perceived as too broad.  It seems quite specific, even including an example of what I want.  Furthermore, once I discovered the solution, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [Shopify Permalink Cart Preloading](https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization/cart/use-permalinks-to-preload-cart)

Using a permalink to create a cart with one or more items in it, extra parameters can be added to the URL that provide additional information (including shipping address, but especially including data such as an affiliate id).

For example,

> example-store.myshopify.com/cart/*variant_id*:*quantity*?ref=*external_referral_id*

will result in a cart that, when checked out and completed, will store the referral ID with the order.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify allows to add some properties to the line items associated with an order. So, You can add properties to the products before adding to cart.
for that you can Refer the URL: https://cartjs.org/pages/reference#core-api-add-item

Now from all your orders you can filter them through the properties in their line items.